# Why there are no commands defined in the make namespace?

Tags: php, laravel, webserver, laravel-artisan

I have installed laravel via composer. I have created the database I need and I'm just trying to add the models I need. So I have tried the artisan command :

```
php artisan make:model Task
```

but it returned the following error :

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                              
  There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.
```

Maybe I have to install other components for artisan ? How can I fix this?

Comment: From which directory are executing this command?

Comment: Which Laravel version?

Comment: probably you are using laravel 4,in laravel 4 there is no make command

Comment: @ThomasSnijder Is the same folder of laravel applicaiton with the following files and folders : `app      bootstrap      composer.lock    phpunit.xml  readme.md   vendor
artisan  composer.json  CONTRIBUTING.md  public       server.php
`

Comment: artisan --version returned the output :  `Laravel Framework version 4.2.17` . Is Laravel 4

Comment: See comment of Nehal Hasnayeen, no make command in Laravel 4. Upgrade to Laravel 5 to make us of that command.

Comment: @ThomasSnijder Yeh you're right, I upgraded to laravel 5, now is working, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No make command in laravel 4, I have upgraded my laravel application to 5.1 and now it is working

Comment: You should set this as the answer.